# Validate Select in AdminBSB template

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the AdminBSB template for my my asp.net website. But I am facing a problem with it.

my problem is how to validate combobox. I have search Internet and tried many solutions but non of them worked. I have added required and made the value of the first item is empty but it did not work.

here is my code
{

```
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="CmbMekaMainHotel" class="form-control" runat="server" 
                              DataSourceID="MekaHotelsDataSource" DataTextField="Hotel_ArName"  OnDataBound="CmbMekaMainHotel_DataBound"
                              DataValueField="Hotel_ID" required>
                          </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MekaHotelsDataSource" runat="server" 
                              ConnectionString="<%$ #### %>" 
                              SelectCommand="SELECT '' as [Hotel_ID], N'Please Select' as [Hotel_ArName]  union SELECT [Hotel_ID], [Hotel_ArName] FROM [Hotels] ">

                          </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

}

Any help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you edit and add your code which contains the issue ? Detail what you have tried and why it doesn't work

Comment: I have added my code